# How to add padding to checked radio button css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to add padding to my radio button after being checked.
I use this code for the radio button

```js
function shout(e) {
  $(".no-dd").removeAttr("checked");
  var radio_value = $(e).attr("id");
  $("#" + radio_value).attr("checked", "true");
}
```

```css
.cool input {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  border: 0.8px solid #121a21;
  border-radius: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
}

.cool input[type=radio]:checked {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  border: 0.8px solid #121a21;
  border-radius: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: visible;
  background: #121a21;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="cool">
  <input role="radio" type="radio" id="d_sample" class="no-dd" name="rp_select" onclick="shout(this)">
  <label for="d_sample">
    <input role="radio" type="radio" id="d_admple" class="no-dd" name="rp_select" onclick="shout(this)">
    <label for="d_admple">
    </form>
```

The Radio button default after styling is this (UNCHECKED)

[image: Unchecked]

The code above is giving me this after being checked

[image: Checked]

But what I want is this

[image: What I want]

How do I go about achieving what I want, which is the last image.

Comment: I'm checked your code, radio button looks fine for me in the chrome and firefox. [link](https://ibb.co/CKGTM3n).  What browser are you using? Can you add a working example?

Comment: _"I am trying to add padding..."_ I see no padding CSS anywhere. Also, the code you provided isn't producing the result you say that it is

Answer (score -1):

```
.cool input[type=radio]:checked{    
box-sizing: border-box;
height: 13px;
width: 13px;
border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
outline: 0.8px solid #121a21;
border-radius: 50%;
cursor:pointer;
overflow: visible;
background:#121a21;
}
```

Give white border and add your circle with outline parameter.